# Rails query - Intersection of single attribute of 2 large models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So I have 2 models, `ModelOne` and `ModelTwo`, both of which have a `my_field` attribute. I want to count how many distinct `ModelTwo` objects there are, such that `my_field` uniquely exists in `ModelTwo` and not in `ModelOne.`

With a small enough dataset, I could write a simple inefficient function and get the data I need, but both `ModelOne` and `ModelTwo` have several million objects. So I figure that just getting the intersection count of how many `my_field` values are shared between the two tables would be enough, since subtracting that count from `ModelTwo` total count would give me the number I'm looking for.

What's a good, efficient, way to get this intersection count?

Answer (score 0):

You can try left outer join. Something smilar like this.

```
ModelTwo.left_outer_joins(:model_ones).distinct
```